# Match Braces in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match the inner content of the first braces in Java only if the template with braces occurs first. For instance:

```
{FOO}/bar/{BAR} -> "FOO"
/{FOO}/bar/{BAR} -> null
{BAR}/foo/{FOO} -> "BAR"
```

I was tested the following regex which seemed to work `^{(.*?)}` in the online regex testers; however, when I try to do this in Java as `^\\{(.*?)}` it fails. I suspect it has something to do with the braces being misinterpreted. Currently, the Java regex doesn't match any of the above strings.

```
protected Optional<String> getHostVariableNameFromTemplate(String template) {
    final String REGEX = "^\\{([^}]*)}";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(template);

    return (matcher.matches()) ? Optional.of(matcher.group(0)) : Optional.empty();
}

@Test // fails
public void getHostVariableNameFromTemplate_shouldReturnFirstVariable() {
    String template = "{SOME_HOST}/foo/{fooId}/bar/{barId}?filter=foobar";
    Optional<String> host = testObj.getHostVariableNameFromTemplate(template);
    assertTrue(host.isPresent());
    assertEquals("SOME_HOST", host.get());
}
```

Comment: Is it run in Android? Then you need to escape `}`.

Comment: No its Spring and I tried escaping }

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "it fails"?

Comment: Don't *only* describe your code. Show it (preferably as [mcve]) so we could debug it properly.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem: https://ideone.com/le0JRt

Comment: @scriptkiddie Have you been probably confused with `match` and `find`?

Comment: I updated the question with an example.

Comment: `matcher.matches()` checks if regex matches *entire* string. If you want to allow for *fragment* of text to be matched by regex use `matcher.find()`.

Comment: Yeah I was also using the wrong group I think. I should have been using `.group(1)` instead of `.group(0)`. Thanks Pshemo!